# e.parameters passing with others parameters

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How can I pass "e" parameters, together with other parameters in a function, this function below that need these parameters.

Thanks Renan Otero.

```
function Selectbox(e ,Name ,NameRow ,Row ,Col ,IDelement ,ID) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var Prodb = app.createListBox().setWidth(125).setName(Name);
  var aux = e.parameter.(Name);
  if(aux = undefined)
    aux = NameRow;
  var ind = getColIndexByNamelink(aux, ID);
  Prodb.setVisibleItemCount(1);
  for (var i = 2; i < lastRow + 1; i++) {
    var Item = sheet.getRange(i, (ind * 1)).getValue();
    if (Item == "OK")
      break;
    else
    Prodb.addItem(Item);
  }
  var grid = app.getElementById(IDelement);
  grid.setWidget(Row, Col, Prodb);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're asking. Can you post the code that calls this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var aux = e.parameter.(Name);
```

should be using square bracket notation

```
var aux = e.parameter[Name];
```

You are not comparing here, you are assigning

```
if(aux = undefined)
```

should be

```
if(aux === undefined)
```